# No options for "Print layout" while animating lines with mmqgis

Tags: qgis-3, animation, mmqgis

I am trying to use the mmqgis animate lines tool to animate some lines. But for some reason the dialogue box has the `"print layout"` section greyed out.

[image: animate lines tool screenshot]

The line layer is called `'POC 3 to POC 4 shape'`, the data looks like this

[image: data screenshot]

I change the directory to somewhere convenient for me and because print layout is greyed out this is the result.

[image: layout not found screenshot]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling mmqgis, I have tried manually installing the plugin by dropping it into the plugins directory and the same problem persisted.

I even tried an older version (last 2016 variant) and of course, QGIS refused to run it as it is incompatible with my version of QGIS (3.2.1)

Anyone else having the same issue?

Ultimately I just want to animate a bunch of lines

Comment: Do you have a print layout set up in this QGIS project?

Comment: @csk this was the issue all along. thank you. after creating a print layout, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because I didnt have a print layout created first.

to do this you simply going to project > new print layout, give it a name, drop the map in and save. then run the animate lines tool from mmqgis.

Thank you to @csk and Reddit user u/clint20040